# NSPerformService "Tweet" with an Image (Twitter.app)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, service, twitter

Is there anyway to `NSPerformService(@"Tweet", [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard]);` with an image? I know that simply text is possible, but i don't know about the image.
If yes, example code would be nice.
Thank you.

PS: for those who don't know, this is only possible if the user has the Twitter.app installed.

Comment: Interesting, I'd never heard of the `NSPerformService()` function before.

Comment: you're always learning :P if you want, i did some example code on how to perform this: http://pastebin.com/LFJfM1Hb

Comment: You shouldn't use the general pasteboard for this. That's the one that the Copy and Paste commands work with—if you use that pasteboard for your service communications, you'll clobber whatever the user has previously Copied.

Comment: Right, what @PeterHosey says: Use `[NSPasteboard pasteboardWithUniqueName]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The types that you can send to a service depends upon the types that the registered application has declared in its `Info.plist`. For `Twitter.app`, this looks like:

```xml
    <key>NSMenuItem</key>
    <dict>
        <key>default</key>
        <string>Tweet</string>
    </dict>
    <key>NSSendTypes</key>
    <array>
        <string>NSStringPboardType</string>
    </array>
```

Unfortunately, this means that you will have to transform the image into a string before it will be accepted by the service.

Comment: Which, in keeping with Twitter norms, would mean uploading the image somewhere and then putting the absolute string of its URL on your pasteboard.